# How to identify selected tab in Acumatica?

Tags: acumatica

I have a custom screen with two filters and in the header section and three tab items with grid controls. I also have a print button which prints grid data in the report. My question is, how I can identify which tab is selected.

For example, I have tab names like Open, Closed and All. If the user selected Closed tab and click on the print button I need to identify the user is in the Closed tab.

Comment: With JavaScript search HTML elements for CSS class tabSelected: document.getElementsByClassName("tabSelected");

Comment: You'll need some workaround to pass the value in BLC if needed, something like a hidden DAC field that is populated by the JavaScript that checks which tab is selected.

Comment: Thanks, will give a try and let you know.

Comment: What if you just move the print button the the TAB? have a print for each tab? then you know which the user clicked if the report is based on the information of the tab

Comment: Hi Brendan, i created a new Report menu and added three print options in it, instead of a button in the each tab.